Typescript Index Signature Template restrictions
I have some Typescript Interfaces that have many repeated, similar fields. For example:
interface Foo {
   person1Name: string;
   person1Address: string;
   person2Name: string;
   person2Address: string;
   category: string;
   department: string;
}

I'm trying to shorten that by using Typescript index signature templates which works great using things like [key: 'person${number}Name']. However, I'd like to limit the number of allow keys to say 5 'person' properties and it's not working as expected.
type AllowedIndex = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;

interface Foo {
   [key: `person${AllowedIndex}Name`]: string;
   [key: `person${AllowedIndex}Address`]: string;
   category: string;
   department: string;
}

The above gives me the error An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.ts(1337).
Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do? Or am I stuck repeating the keys the way I already am?
Here is a TS Playground Link with what I've tried.

If you have several fields per number (name, address, whatever else), consider refactoring to a nested object (probably then using tuple of five such objects). Please help future yourself and let grep person1 src -rn keep working - do not overuse such types unless really necessary, if digits have some real semantic meaning here.

@STerliakov Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I have very little control over the shape of the object coming back as it's from a CMS. The meaning of the numbers is mostly an indicator of the number of allowed items for the given content requested from the CMS.

How about this then?

I would probably write what you're doing this way. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer (although it seems similar to @STerliakov's so maybe they want to write it up first). If not, what am I missing?

Those are both clever solutions! The only thing that may be missing (and perhaps I failed to make that clear in my question) is that the numbered fields should all be optional fields.

Use Partial then like this? If @STerliakov doesn't want to write an answer I'll do it, if that suffices. Does it?

Yes! Thank you! Write up an answer, I"ll accept it

@jcalz go on, we have already discussed that - I'm still a lazy answerer;)

(esp. given that your extends solution should result in a bit faster compilation, if I remember correctly)

TypeScript 4.4 introduced the ability to use pattern or placeholder template literal types (as implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#40598) in index signatures. But `person${AllowedIndex}Name` isn't a pattern template literal type. In fact, it's not even a template literal type at all, in the sense that it gets eagerly evaluated by TypeScript to be the union of string literal types "person1Name" | "person2Name" | "person3Name" | "person4Name" | "person5Name".  And you can't use a union of string literal types  in an index signature.
Instead, you can use mapped types to make an object type whose keys are a union of string literals.  That would look like {[K in `person${AllowedIndex}Name`]: string} if you want the keys to be required, or {[K in `person${AllowedIndex}Name`]?: string} if you want them to be optional. Equivalently you can use a combination of the Partial and Record utility types like Partial<Record<`person${AllowedIndex}Name`, string>>.
Note that mapped types are their own types and you cannot add properties to them. If you want to combine several mapped types you can use an intersection.  Or, if you want to end up with an interface, you can use interface extension to combine the parent mapped types (but only through a named type like Partial or Record) and your added properties. That gives
type AllowedIndex = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;

interface Foo extends
   Partial<Record<`person${AllowedIndex}Name`, string>>,
   Partial<Record<`person${AllowedIndex}Address`, string>> {
   category: string;
   department: string;
}

which you can inspect to make sure it behaves as desired:
type ExpandedFoo = {[K in keyof Foo]: Foo[K]};
/* type ExpandedFoo = {
    category: string;
    department: string;
    person1Name?: string | undefined;
    person2Name?: string | undefined;
    person3Name?: string | undefined;
    person4Name?: string | undefined;
    person5Name?: string | undefined;
    person1Address?: string | undefined;
    person2Address?: string | undefined;
    person3Address?: string | undefined;
    person4Address?: string | undefined;
    person5Address?: string | undefined;
} */

Playground link to code

This was very helpful. I appreciate you adding the additional information and links to documentation. Note that mapped types are their own types and you cannot add properties to them -- that statement sparked a 'light bulb' moment in my brain and explains why some of what I was trying wasn't working. Thank you!

I'm in a slightly different part of my project now that has the same type of fields. I'm trying to group some of those numbered fields together in a loop, so I'm targeting those properties using a template literal. Do you know of a way to allow this type of this without an excessive amount of aliasing? Here is a Playground link to better show what I'm asking.

That isn't a [mre] and a comment isn't a great place to ask a question. You've got... an array? And you're indexing into it with... string keys? Don't get it, sorry. Where does "Alt" even come in? Are you sure this problem doesn't go away if you fix your typos? Anyway, this isn't the right place for such a discussion. If you can't figure it out you might want to open a new question post for it. Good luck!

You could achieve this via something like this:
type AllowedIndex = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;

type PersonStuff = 
   { [TKey in `person${AllowedIndex}Name`]: string } &
   { [TKey in `person${AllowedIndex}Address`]: string };

interface Foo extends PersonStuff {
   category: string;
   department: string;
}

See TS Playground link.

Thanks for the hint. I followed now a best practice from Matt Pocock to prefix all generics with "T" + name.
